# Is it possible to access the speech recognition on Chrome on the iPad?

Tags: ipad, google-chrome

Chrome on the iPad support speech recognition for your search.
You can also use that [within your own web page](http://www.labnol.org/software/add-speech-recognition-to-website/19989/).

But it doesn't work on [my] iPad 2 with Chrome.

I can't find anything on the web indicating whether it is or is not supported on the iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Because of Apple politics, that say apps can not "duplicate features that come with the iPhone" all full-featured browsers in app store must be a shells for Safari (default iOS webkit). This means that Google Chrome for iOS actualy just different looking Safari and does not include Chrome-specific API's.